# Call $n\in\Bbb N$ "balanced" if the sum of its digits equals the count of its divisors. How many "balanced" numbers are there up to $m$?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion, divisor-counting-function

I recently stumbled across a problem about numbers' divisor count (more specifically, how many positive integers are equal to the square of their divisor count - answer was 2: they are 1 and 9).

But I then tried and make it more complex. It goes like this:

> Any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is called "balanced" if and only if the sum of its digits equals the count of its divisors (1 and n included).

Examples of "balanced" numbers would be $1, 2, 11, 22, 36, 84, 101, ...$

I had already found a function that returns the amount of divisors (if $n = \prod_{i=0}^ k p_i^{\alpha_i}$,  $\delta(n) = \prod_{i=0}^ k ({\alpha_i}+1)$), but can't find a bond between digits and count of divisors.

To get some data I coded a program that would give me an idea and it seems that those numbers get rarer the bigger they get. Here's a small table of values:

| n | "balanced" numbers up to n |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 6 |
| 1000 | 33 |
| 10000 | 211 |
| 100000 | 1559 |

I am wondering:

- if there is a way to find the count of "balanced" numbers up to $m \in \mathbb{N}$;
- if there are infinitely many "balanced" numbers.

Comment: "how many positive integers are equal to the square of their divisor count - answer was 2: they are 1 and 3." $3$ has two divisors, so $3=2^2$?

Comment: As a cheap remark, the infinitude of such numbers would follow from a proof that there were infinitely many primes of the form $10^n+1$.  Also, this is [A057531](https://oeis.org/A057531) in OEIS, but that page doesn't contain a lot of information.  Maybe some of the references help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I forgot to square it, I meant 9.

Comment: Problems relating number theoretic properties with base related properties are often very difficult since the digits of an integer are not an intrinsic property of the numbers, they depends on the base being $10$ which is a very artificial choice.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime with digit sum eight, then $10p$ will qualify. Such primes are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A062343 with no indication as to whether it is known whether there are infinitely many.

Comment: Similarly, if $p$ is a prime with digit sum $32$, then $1000p$ qualifies, and such primes are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A106768

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do not think that it can be proven but there should be infinite many primes with digits sum $8$

Comment: @lulu But the largest prime of the form $10^n+1$ is probably $101$

Comment: @Peter, sad but true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of divisors of some positive integer can only be determined by factoring it. But the count is routine for , say , $m\le 10^{10}$

I do not think that we can prove that there are infinite many balanced numbers , but it is extremely likely that there are infinite many primes with digit sum $8$ which would already be enough to establish infinite many such numbers , as pointed out above.

Count of the number of balanced numbers below $10^k$ for $k=1,2,\cdots ,8$ :

```
1   2
2   6
3   33
4   211
5   1559
6   11405
7   91417
8   786349
```

Comment: For each balanced number, you have this specific value (sum of digits, or count of divisors). Can you add the average of this value, in your treatment. Just to see if the profile of balanced numbers are like 6003021, or like 6798978, 7 small digits or 7 big digits). And, (it is certainly more complex), it may be useful to compare these statistics, in base 10, and in base 8 or 16.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this simplifies the thing to prove (and thanks to the others ho suggested that approach too). I have another question though: how in the world did you find the numbers after $10^7$?!

Comment: PARI/GP can factor the numbers upto $10^8$ within a reasonable amount of time , simply by brute force !

Answer (score 1):

Upto $10^9$ , we have the following values and counts :

```
1  1
2  3
4  57
8  2246
9  15
10  110
12  2579
14  290
16  101016
18  25383
19  1
20  30062
22  461
24  522698
25  4
26  322
27  508
28  51003
30  244
32  1679303
34  94
36  2067317
38  34
40  428096
44  8728
45  381
46  2
48  1777362
50  169
52  985
54  28363
56  16336
60  1812
63  1
64  7439
72  608
```

The number of balanced numbers and the average value are :

```
gp > sum(j=1,length(a),j*a[j])/vecsum(a)*1.0
%4 = 37.145238259866364289306848219426822463
gp > vecsum(a)
%5 = 6754033
gp >
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, very interesting. We can 'see' that it is very regular ; proportion seems very similar in numbers with many small digits, and numbers with many big digits.

Comment: My previous comment was probably wrong. For very big numbers, in average, number of divisors is ln(n) ; we have obviouly some disparity, with numbers with only 2 digits, and numbers with much more than $ln(n)$ divisors.  For same very big numbers, sum of digits is in average $\frac{4.5}{ln(10)} \times ln(n) = 1.95 ln(n)$ ; this is an average, and this distibution can be estimated with a gaussian. We have this gaussian, and another curve a little more complex ; each integer is a 'random' value in those 2 gaussians.

Comment: Probability to have same value on both axes should be higher when sum of digits is betwen $ln(n)$ and $1.95 ln(n) $  And the range of possible values for $\sigma(n)$ and for $sd(n)$ (sum of digits) slowly increase, so probability to 'pick' same number in both axes should slowly decrease.

Comment: Excuse me @Peter,  it seems really interesting but I can't understand what the columns mean in the table. Could you make it clear? Thanks.

Comment: @Franci12 The first column is the digitsum (and also the number of divisors) and the second the number of cases where this value occurs , in the range $[1,10^9]$. The average value is about $37$ and $6754033$ is the number of balanced numbers in this range.