# Proving that there are infinite primes with digit sum 8 in base 10

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, decimal-expansion, divisor-counting-function

I recently wrote about a problem I cam up with while thinking about number theory, which you can find on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712174/call-n-in-bbb-n-balanced-if-the-sum-of-its-digits-equals-the-count-of-its-di). Long story short, I'm trying to prove there are infinite natural numbers such that their divisors count ($1$ and $n$ included) equals the sum of their digits.

Among the many useful comments and answers, I read about a really clever way of proving the infinite amount of such numbers (if the following statement is true), which is by proving that there are an infinite amount of primes $p_i$ with digit sum $8$.

In that case, $10p$ will have eight divisors and will have digit sum eight.

I thought of some examples of such numbers, and I found a couple:

- made of eight ones and n zeros (starting with 1 and ending with 1) (e.g. $1001110110101$ - I don't know whether this specific one is or not a prime, it's just an example)
- $10...07$
- $70...01$
- $50...03$

I thought about using Dirichlet theorem, but it states that there are infinite primes in the form:

$a + nb$

With $gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, but I don't think it's feasible because it doesn't include all possible values of n.

Does anybody know something I can work on, or he can help with?

Comment: I would not expect this to be solvable.  There are very few classes of numbers which are known to contain infinitely many primes.  Dirichlet, sure, but that's really not relevant here.

Comment: @lulu is there a way of knowing if a problem is or isn't solvable?

Comment: No, unfortunately.  Here, though...there are a long list of problems, like are there infinitely many primes of the form $10^k+1$ and such, that nobody has made progress on, and this feels like those.

Comment: Note, of course, that the $10^k+1$ problem is equivalent to yours, only with digit sum $2$.

Comment: The number of candidates with n digits (n digit numbers with digit sum 8 and ending in 1, 3, or 7 and starting with 1 to 7) is a 6th degree polynomial in n. The heuristic number of primes up to n digits is a 7th degree polynomial. So I’d assume there are infinitely many, but proving it would be really hard.

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean that the digit sum is _exactly_ $8$, not that the digit sum is $8\pmod n$ for some fixed $n$, correct?

Comment: @MJD correct. We're talking about numbers that multiplied by 10 will have 1, 2, 5, n as prime factors, thus 8 divisors. Therefore we need the digit sum to be exactly 8, not a modularly congruent value.

Comment: Let's say $n$ is not divisible by $2$ or $5$ and it has $f$ factors and a digit sum of $fk^2$ then $10^{k-1}n$ has divisor count equal to it's digit sum. We need infinite numbers of this form. Note that this is the general case of a prime ($f=2$) with digit sum $8$ ($f=2$ and $k=2$)

Comment: I see no chance to prove that infinite many primes with digitsum $8$ exist , but we can expect that this is the case. The family $70\cdots 01$ should already do the job.

Comment: $30\cdots 05$ is never prime since it is divisible by $5$

Comment: @quantus14 This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2336050) has a reference to a proof that for all sufficiently large $n$ not divisible by $3$ a prime with digit sum $n$ exists.

Comment: @nickgard Although this result does not help to answer the question , it is a remarkable result which I would not expected to be within reach.